How to prevent unhandled exception from appearing in the UI?
I am using Svelte 4 with
"@sveltejs/kit": "^2.0.0",
"@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^3.0.0",
"svelte": "^4.2.7",

When I run the app using:
npm run dev

which calls vite dev underneath
and try to access an invalid URL like http://localhost:5173// I get a good error screen:

corresponding to routes/+error.svelte. But if I run the app using:
npm run preview

which calls vite preview underneath
this is what I get:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:637:13)
    at file:///Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/preview/index.js:86:33
    at call (file:///Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BKbDVx1T.js:43000:7)
    at next (file:///Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BKbDVx1T.js:42944:5)
    at /Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/sirv/build.js:180:28
    at call (file:///Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BKbDVx1T.js:43000:7)
    at next (file:///Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BKbDVx1T.js:42944:5)
    at file:///Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BKbDVx1T.js:54650:28
    at viteAssetMiddleware (file:///Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BKbDVx1T.js:69268:7)

I am not posting a screenshot but this error gets echoed to the UI (i.e., printed in the web browser). How can I avoid this and get same behavior as with npm run dev?

FYI, I think in theory, // in the URL path is invalid. So the server should probably really send back 400, and not 404. If you use adapter-static, then your build just consists of static HTML, CSS, client-side JS, images, etc. files, and it's the server that hosts these files that should be configured to deal with the // case.
